# Disabling onClickListener for Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, onclicklistener

How can I disable onClicklistener for GoogleMap, GoogleMap’s `setOnMapClickListener()`
 method, like we have setClickable(true)/setClickable(false) for other  android widgets.

Comment: `setAllGesturesEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 3):

The trick is

```
mapview.setOnClickListener(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some methods of GoogleMap api like

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
```

but those will not work in this case you better go with this implementation

```
  if(null!=googleMap){ 
    googleMap(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {                  

    @Override                
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latlng) {    
      if(your validation) { 
      //if true then go to Google map.    
      }  else {    
      // if false then  don't go to Google map.     
      }    
    }  
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**To Disable ScrollGesture:**

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
```

**To Disable All the Gesture, Use below code:**

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
```

**And To Disable MapToolbar, Use:**

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```

Comment: The second one will be fine for your case.

Answer (score 0):

try `mMapFragment.getView().setClickable(false);`

or

```
yourmap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
```